# Can a post ID be 0?

Tags: database

I couldn't find explicit confirmation of this, can it be 0?

Comment: Simple answer, no. ID's start @ 1

Comment: Why not check the codex?

Answer (score 10):

No, post ID can not be 0 in the DB. But the value 0 has a special meaning in the code, indicating the currently handled post (if the context is set up correctly)